# Can't run bash file inside ZSH

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I've placed a bash file inside `.zshrc` and tried all different ways to run it every time I open a new terminal window or source `.zshrc` but no luck.

FYI: it was working fine on `.bashrc`

here is `.zshrc` script:

```
#Check if ampps is running
bash ~/ampps_runner.sh & disown
```

Different approach:

```
#Check if ampps is running
sh ~/ampps_runner.sh & disown
```

Another approach:

```
#Check if ampps is running
% ~/ampps_runner.sh & disown
```

All the above approaches didn't work (meaning it supposes to run an app named ampps but it doesn't in zsh.

**Note:** It was working fine before switching to zsh from bash. so it does not have permission or syntax problems.

**Update:** content of ampps_runner.sh

```
#! /usr/bin/env

echo "########################"
echo "Checking for ampps server to be running:"


check=$(pgrep -f "/usr/local/ampps" )

#[  -z "$check" ] && echo "Empty: Yes" || echo "Empty: No"

if [ -z "$check" ]; then
    echo "It's not running!"
    cd /usr/local/ampps
    echo password | sudo -S ./Ampps
else
    echo "It's running ..."
fi
```

Comment: Define “didn’t work”.

Comment: @4ae1e1 it simply won't run

Comment: Add `setopt xtrace` to the top of `.zshrc` to trace. Also, `command &!` is enough to disown.

Comment: @4ae1e1setopt xtrace print out so many lines i can't even scroll :), Thanks for the tip though

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini Have you gave proper permission to `ampps_runner.sh` ?

Comment: Try  adding '-x', it will provide good level of logging. If you try to run the command interactively from zsh does it work ? Does the program need input ? what happen if you try without disown ?

Comment: `zsh` is **not** fully `bash` compatible, [https://serverfault.com/a/98772/547884](https://serverfault.com/a/98772/547884)

Comment: @ThinkMatic Irrelevant; the OP is never trying to run `ampps_runner` as a `zsh` script (except *maybe* in the last case, if the script doesn't have an explicit shebang).

Comment: @ImanKianrostami it's not about the permission as I said before, it was working fine in bash, it supposes to run an app named ampps but it doesn't.

Comment: @ThinkMatic both zshrc and ampps_runner.sh have sha_bang of #! /usr/bin/env

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini, not sure if it's your issue however the shebang shouldn't have a space after the exclamation mark.

Comment: @Geoffrey Had no effect. Thanks anyway.

Comment: According to @ThinkMatic as I need it to run those bash I had to remove zsh and go back to bash. if anyone has any proper answer please put it here for later use, thanks.

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini, have you read my comments carefully? I didn't suggest you to remove your zsh or advise you go back to bash.

Comment: @ThinkMatic I know, but I didn't have spare time to wait for this problem to be solved, so I had to remove it to get my scripts back to working and if any solution have found then I'll switch to zsh again.

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini, I posted a comment to remind you about some **incompatible features** in `zsh`, after your **original** question. Then, you edited it multiple times, and I didn't comments anymore.

Comment: @ThinkMatic I appreciate that you mention that.

Answer (score 0):

(1) I believe **`~/.ampps_runner.sh`** is a **`bash`** script, so, its first line should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
```

not

```
#! /usr/bin/env
```

(2) Then, the call in **`zsh`** script (`~/.zshrc`) should be:

```
~/ampps_runner.sh
```

(3) Note: **`~/.ampps_runner.sh`** should be `executable`. Change it to executable:

```
$ chmod +x ~/ampps_runner.sh
```

Comment: I've done all the above and check every sha-bang possible still no luck, and as I said before it was executable because it was working before switching to zsh.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run `bash` temporarily from a `zsh` terminal is to

```
exec bash
```

or just

```
bash
```

Then you can run commands you previously could only run in bash. An example

```
help exec
```

To exit

```
exit
```

Now you are back in your original shell

If you want to know your default shell

```
echo $SHELL
```

or

```
set | grep SHELL=
```

If you want to reliably know your current shell

```
ps -p $$
```

Or if you want just the shell name you might use

```
ps -p $$ | awk "NR==2" | awk '{ print $4 }' | tr -d '-'
```

And you might just put that last one in a function for later, just know that it is only available if it was sourced in a current shell.

```
whichShell(){
   local defaultShell=$(echo $SHELL | tr -d '/bin/')
   echo "Default: $defaultShell" 

   local currentShell=$(ps -p $$ | awk "NR==2" | awk '{ print $4 }' | tr -d '-')
   echo "Current: $currentShell"
}
```

Call the method to see your results

```
whichShell
```

Comment: Also... you might be able to just run `bash -c 'your command here'` like `bash -c 'help help'`